# HTML: set id for onclick from list

Tags: python, html, string, list, flask

Apologies if this question has already been asked. I'm new to HTML and I'm not familiar with the words I should use to find help with.

I'm using Flask and HTML to make a website.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>Click the result you want to investigate</h3>
{% for r in results %}
  <p id=r["links"] onclick="myFunction(id)"> {{r["title"]}} ({{r["address_snippet"]}})  </p>
{% endfor %}

<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "CLICKED HERE";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to print out a list of names, and etc to the screen. The user will click one name, this name will then be returned to a Python function for further analysis.

As a first attempt, I just want to change the text from the name to "CLICKED HERE". However, regardless of which name I click, only the first entry changes.

I can't figure out how to set the id from the container. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use `this.id` when passing it into the function, or `myFunction(r["links"])`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't seem to work either. 

*  If I change: onclick="myFunction(id)" -> onclick="myFunction(this.id)", I see the same behaviour.
* If I change: onclick="myFunction(id)" -> onclick="myFunction(r["links"])", no click works
* If I change: function myFunction(id) -> function myFunction(this.id), on click works.
Thoughts?

Comment: Well for one, you need to alter the quotes because you have nested "" inside ""

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could tell me how I should alter it?

Comment: `onclick="myFunction(list['links'])"` might work. If not, you may need to escape the string entirely. not sure how flask templates work on that end

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work :( I think the issue is completely unrelated to Flask. It's an html/javascript issue, I believe.

Comment: This should work `<p id="{{r["links"]}}" onclick="myFunction('{{r["links"]}}')"`

Comment: Could you post a sample of how the rendered html looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your code like this, so you get the actual value from the variable `r["links"]`, by adding the brackets `{{r["links"]}}`

```
<p id="{{r["links"]}}" onclick="myFunction('{{r["links"]}}')"
```